# Aurelia - repeat.for sorted by value converter failing in IE 11

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a select list that is sorted via a value converted. The sort direction can be changed by two buttons, ascending and descending.

**The root cause appears to be using a size attribute on the select element (see demo).**

Any suggestions on a workaround would be much appricatied.

This feature is working in all browsers except IE 11.

[Bug Demo Project](https://github.com/Ra-Sedgwick/aurelia-select-bug)

Environment details.

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Aurelia Version: 1.3.0
- Node Version: 8.11.3
- NPM Version:6.1.0
- Browser: IE 11

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue on table elements but maybe a selects are effected too? Take a look at this workaround if you haven't already. Maybe it will also work with selects? https://github.com/aurelia/html-template-element/issues/3

Comment: Maybe I misread your issue. The above might not be helpful.

Comment: They are similar, but those workarounds will not help unfortunately.

Comment: Both your sample code and the GistRun link you provide crash with an error `Promise is undefined` in IE11.  Do you get this error or something else (and if so, what)?

Comment: Please add a small sample showcasing your problem to this question. A link to your code is fine, but should be accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in the aurelia-binding library and or IE.

See discussion on their GitHub for possible workarounds.

[aurelia-binding: Issue #708](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/708)